# Selecting two specific mysql table rows in a single query

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table with 20 entries. They are sorted by date (date is a column name >_>) in descending order. How would I go about selecting ONLY the newest entry and the 15th oldest entry?

I am getting all 15 results by doing the following query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable m WHERE col1 = "zzz" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: I believe you can only do this in two queries, unless you do some union select magic.
LIMIT 1 and LIMIT 1,15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
          FROM mytable a 
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
         WHERE a.col1 = "zzz" 
      ORDER BY a.date DESC) x
 WHERE x.rank IN (1, 15)
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting "Unknown table 'a'"

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use UNION of two SELECTs

```
(SELECT * FROM mytable m WHERE col1 = "zzz" ORDER BY date LIMIT 1, 15)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM mytable m WHERE col1 = "zzz" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

UPDATE:

added parenthesis